# How do I link to a URL that contains encoded forward slash?

Tags: html, encoding, url-encoding

[Here's a page](http://www.last.fm/music/45+King%2FTake+6) at the URL `http://www.last.fm/music/45+King%2FTake+6`

If I link to it in a page, using this HTML:

```
<a href="http://last.fm/music/45+King%2FTake+6">Link</a>
```

then the browser 404s because it ends up [here](http://www.last.fm/music/45+King/Take+6), at `http://www.last.fm/music/45+King/Take+6`. i.e., the `%2F` is decoded to `/`.

Why does that decoding happen? Why does a URL I can successfully paste into the browser not work as a link in a page? I feel like I'm going mad...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the "Here's a page" link in my question was working fine, while my link in a local static HTML file wasn't... that was confusing.

The difference is that locally my link was to the `last.fm` domain, rather than `www.last.fm`.

So, [the link to last.fm](http://last.fm/music/45+King%2FTake+6) redirects to the `www.last.fm` version, and in that redirection the `%2F` is decoded.

So I just need to [link to www.last.fm](http://www.last.fm/music/45+King%2FTake+6) instead!